# Nested tag extraction with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How it is possible to iterate over all tags in a specific tag using jsoup? For example, the HTML file looks like

```
<br><input ....>
    <A HREF=...> <i>some texts</i>
    <A HREF=...>
<br><input ....>
    <A HREF=...> <i>some texts</i>
    <A HREF=...>
<br><input ....>
    <A HREF=...> <i>some texts</i>
    <A HREF=...>
...
```

So, for each `br`, I want to iterate over the tags `input`, `a`, `i` and `a`. The statement

```
Element element = doc.select("br").first();
```

Will return only `br` which is not suitable.

UPDATE:

If I use `Elements element = doc.select("br");` then how can I iterate over `element`? If I use

```
Elements element = doc.select("br");
Element e2 = element.get(0).select("i").first();
```

Then e2 will be null!!

Comment: `Elements e=doc.select("br");` and iterate over is not working ?

Comment: for `Elements` it says `error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: There is an error somewhere because it's something that exists (i've tried some time ago) and it's even on the main page https://jsoup.org/

Comment: OK. I added `import org.jsoup.select.Elements;` Please see the updated post

Comment: is the content on a website I can go to test ? if yes give url (in comment if you want to delete after and let no trace)

Comment: Problem is that not all `br`s have `i`. For this reason I have to manually iterate over `br`s and check somethings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149624/discussion-between-azro-and-mahmood).

Answer (score 0):

You can't read over `input`, `a`, `i` and `a` from `br` because there are no children of the `br`, because that's `select` do : select the children of the element

---

The problem is being seen in chat - I'll edit once it's ok